# Shifting a sort order in a table causes IIS to crash

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5

I have the following update code for an entry:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditClient(ModifyClientViewModel model) {
  Clients clients = await db.Clients.FindAsync(new Guid(model.ClientId));
  if(clients == null) { return HttpNotFound(); }
  try {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
      TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
      clients.ClientName = ti.ToTitleCase(model.ClientName.Trim());
      clients.CityId = new Guid(model.CityId);
      clients.SortOrder = MakeRoom(model.SortOrder, model.ClientId);
      clients.Active = model.Active;
      clients.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
      clients.TouchedBy = User.GetClaimValue("UserGuid");
      db.Entry(clients).State = EntityState.Modified;
      await db.SaveChangesAsync();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
  } catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) {
// removed
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

The important line is Line 11, which calls MakeRoom(), where I need to be able to shift the sort order of the entry in question, assuming it is changed.

Now, a word about the sort order: It is a `short` (smallint) column in SQL Server 2012, because there will probably never be more than a few hundred entries anyhow. These are sequential numbers from 1 on up. There will be no gaps in the number sequence (deletions will pull everyone else down), so pulling the max value from that column will also describe the number of rows there are. While two rows can have the same SortOrder (the column allows duplicates for the sorting code to function), this is not supposed to be a persistent state -- it will exist only as long as the actual sort code is running. Once the sorting is done, no duplicate should exist.

If anyone remembers their first-year programming classes, this recursion should be analogous to a “bubble sort” where an element bubbles up to where it is supposed to be. Except here we are “bubbling” by actually changing the row’s SortOrder value.

I have some code that is *supposed* to be a recursive algorithm that takes the desired position, and the ID of the current position, and brings the current position close to the desired position by swapping with the next closer item before looping back onto itself. Once current = desired, the recursion is supposed to end, punting the desired value back to the code above.

Here is what I have made:

```
public short MakeRoom(short newSort, string id) {
  var currentClient = db.Clients.Find(new Guid(id));
  short currentSort = currentClient.SortOrder;
  if(currentSort != newSort) { // need to shift the current value
    short shiftSort = (currentSort < newSort ? currentSort++ : currentSort--); //are we shifting up or down?
    var shiftClient = db.Clients.Where(x => x.SortOrder == shiftSort).First();
    Clients clients = db.Clients.Find(shiftClient.ClientId);
    clients.SortOrder = currentSort; // give the next row the current client's sort number
    db.Entry(clients).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    currentClient.SortOrder = shiftSort; // give the current row the next row's sort number
    db.Entry(currentClient).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    MakeRoom(newSort, id); //One swap done, proceed to the next swap.
  }
  return newSort;
}
```

As you can see, my “base condition” is whether current = desired, and if it does match, all the code is supposed to be ignored in favour of the return statement. If it doesn’t match, the code executes one shift, and then calls itself to conduct the next shift (re-evaluating the current sort value via the ID of the current client because the current sort number is now different due to the just-executed prior shift). Once all shifts are done and current = desired, the code exits with the return statement.

I was hoping someone could examine my logic and see if it is where my problem lies. I seem to be having an infinite loop that doesn’t actually touch the DB, because none of the values in the DB actually get altered -- IIS just ends up crashing.

---

**Edit 1:** Found the stack overflow. Turns out the problem is with

```
    var shiftClient = db.Clients.Where(x => x.SortOrder == shiftSort).First();
```

Problem is, I am not sure why. In the prior line, I had set shiftSort to be one off (depending on the direction) from the current sort. I then want to grab the ClientID via this shiftSort value (which is the SortOrder). Since there should be only one such SortOrder value in the column, I should be able to do a search for it using the line above. But apparently it throws a stack overflow.

So, to be specific: Let's say I went after a client with a SortOrder of 53. I want him to end up with a SortOrder of 50. The prior line takes that 50 (the newSort) and discovers that it is less than the currentSort, so it assigns the shiftSort a value of currentSort-- (53 - 1 = 52). The line above is supposed to take that value of 52, and return a row where that 52 exists, so that on the following rows the ClientID of 52 can be used to modify that line to be 53 (the swap).

Suggestions? I am not understanding why I am experiencing a stack overflow here.

---

**Edit 2:** Revamped by MakeRoom method, but I am still experiencing a Stack Overflow on the affected line:

```
public short MakeRoom(short newSort, string id) {
  Clients currentClient = db.Clients.Find(new Guid(id));
  short currentSort = currentClient.SortOrder;
  if(currentSort != newSort) { // need to shift the current sort
    short shiftSort = (currentSort < newSort ? currentSort++ : currentSort--);
    Clients shiftClient = db.Clients.Where(x => x.SortOrder == shiftSort).FirstOrDefault(); //Stack Overflow is here -- why??
    shiftClient.SortOrder = currentSort;
    db.Entry(shiftClient).State = EntityState.Modified;
    currentClient.SortOrder = shiftSort;
    db.Entry(currentClient).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    MakeRoom(newSort, id);
  }
  return newSort;
}
```

---

**Edit 3:** I have altered my MakeRoom method again:

```
public void MakeRoom(short newSort, string id) {
  var currentClient = db.Clients.Find(new Guid(id));
  short currentSort = currentClient.SortOrder;
  if(currentSort < newSort) {
    var set = db.Clients.Where(x => x.SortOrder > currentSort && x.SortOrder <= newSort).OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder).ToList();
    short i = set.First().SortOrder;
    set.ForEach(c => {
      c.SortOrder = i--;
      c.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
      c.TouchedBy = User.GetClaimValue("UserGuid");
      db.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
    });
    db.SaveChanges();
  } else if(currentSort > newSort) {
    var set = db.Clients.Where(x => x.SortOrder >= newSort && x.SortOrder < currentSort).OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder).ToList();
    short i = set.First().SortOrder;
    set.ForEach(c => {
      c.SortOrder = i++;
      c.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
      c.TouchedBy = User.GetClaimValue("UserGuid");
      db.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
    });
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

But even though the debugger clearly walks through the code and in the right way, the actual DB values do not get changed.

Comment: I'd save row id and sort value in a `Dictionary<string, short>` then sort the dictionary. Once it's sorted, iterate and update your db items _instead of sending db requests for every order step and have EF track each of these temporary changes_.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your method. Do you have an example online you can point me toward?

Comment: Are you trying to write your own sort function for learning purposes or are you just trying to reset the `SortOrder`?

Comment: I am trying to change the SortOrder values in a cascading fashion. Say I have ItemX with a SortOrder of 53. Three items away, I have ItemY at SortOrder of 50. When all is said and done, I want ItemX to have a SortOrder of 50, and ItemY with a SortOrder of 51, and those other items between 50 and 53 incremented by one (to shift them up and make room for ItemX).

Comment: Going in the other direction, say I have ItemG with a SortOrder of 22, and I have ItemU with a SortOrder of 48. If I want to bring ItemG down to 48 in the SortOrder, ItemU would end up with a SortOrder of 47, and everything between 48 and 22 would be decremented by 1 to ensure no gaps exist.

Comment: The entire method is recursive (see how it calls itself at the end of the If?) so it works stepwise until the fundamental condition -- that the current Sort equals the desired sort -- is met. With that said, this will be in an admin section, and rarely touched (it's not like site visitors will be hammering this script), but is vital for the admin section to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. My. Goodness. Talk about overlooking the single screw that caused the house to collapse.

My problem was not with the line that was causing the stack overflow -- my problem was with the line immediately prior:

```
short shiftSort = (currentSort < newSort ? currentSort++ : currentSort--);
```

Can you see the problem? I didn’t. Until now. While attempting to implement the [solution provided by Jasen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37147063/932002) (thank you for your efforts, Good Sir, they were greatly appreciated), I was forced to go through my code a bit more carefully, and I noticed something strange: the increments/decrements. Those are supposed to be for altering the actual value of the item being incremented/decremented, even if it is part of an assignment. So *no wonder* my script was f**cking up -- I was changing the value of `currentSort` at the same time I was assigning it to `shiftSort`.

What I did was two-fold: since there wasn’t any real need to pass a value back, I altered the original HttpPost method as such:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditClient(ModifyClientViewModel model) {
  Clients clients = await db.Clients.FindAsync(new Guid(model.ClientId));
  if(clients == null) { return HttpNotFound(); }
  try {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
      MakeRoom(model.SortOrder, clients.SortOrder);
      TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
      clients.ClientName = ti.ToTitleCase(model.ClientName.Trim());
      clients.CityId = new Guid(model.CityId);
      clients.SortOrder = model.SortOrder;
      clients.Active = model.Active;
      clients.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
      clients.TouchedBy = User.GetClaimValue("UserGuid");
      db.Entry(clients).State = EntityState.Modified;
      await db.SaveChangesAsync();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
  } catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) {
    // Ignore
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Notice how the MakeRoom() is moved to the front, and given only the Source and Destination values? No more need to pass an ID.

Then for the actual method:

```
public void MakeRoom(short newSort, short oldSort) {
  if(oldSort != newSort) { // need to shift the current sort
    short shiftSort = (oldSort < newSort ? (short)(oldSort + 1) : (short)(oldSort - 1));
    Clients currentClient = db.Clients.Where(x => x.SortOrder == oldSort).FirstOrDefault();
    currentClient.SortOrder = shiftSort;
    db.Entry(currentClient).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Clients shiftClient = db.Clients.Where(x => x.SortOrder == shiftSort).FirstOrDefault();
    shiftClient.SortOrder = oldSort;
    db.Entry(shiftClient).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    MakeRoom(newSort, shiftSort);
  }
}
```

Now look at the assignment to shiftSort - I assign it the value of oldSort modified by a single digit. This, I am shamed to say, has made all the difference.

My code now works perfectly, and instantly even over many dozens of intermediary items. I can take an item that had a SortOrder of 3, and move it to a SortOrder of 53, and everything from 53 down to 4 gets shifted down one perfectly to make room (at SortOrder 53) for the item that formerly had a SortOrder of 3.

The nice thing about this method is that it can be used equally well for deletions (to prevent gaps in the numbering) and additions (when you want the new item somewhere other than the end). For deletions you just shift everything after the deleted item (say, SortOrder 33 to Max SortOrder) down one, and for additions you shift everything from the insertion point to the Max SortOrder up one, then insert your value.

I hope this helps anyone who comes after me, and the fates help them with Google -- they will get reams of results that talk about sorting and paging *output*, and precious little about changing the *value* of the sort order for each entry between a source and a destination value.

Answer (score 0):

Let the database sort this for you.

```
var first = db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Guid == guid);

var set = db.Clients
    .Where(c => c.SortOrder >= first.SortOrder)
    .OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder).ToList();

int i = set.First().SortOrder;  // or 1

set.ForEach(c => {
    c.SortOrder = i++;
    db.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
});
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I am not looking to sort the output. I am looking to re-value every entry between ItemX and ItemY. Say you have ItemY with a SortOrder of 53. That means, on the client side it will be in the 53rd place in the list. Now I want it to be in the 50th place, with items formerly in the 50th, 51st and 52nd places to end up in the 51st, 52nd and 53rd places.

Comment: Wait… I think I see what you are doing. Not sure I understand it yet, but lemmie work on it.

Comment: Actually, no. This just moves *all* the SortOrder values. I need to shift only a set of values between a start point and an end point. The start point value needs to move to the end point, and everything between the end point and the start point needs to shift one value toward the start point. How do I set a start point and an end point in your example?

Comment: You can narrow the query before the `OrderBy()`

Comment: Please see my Edit 3 above. Still having issues.

Comment: Because I don't actually need the ID anymore, I am just passing in the two SortOrder values, original and destination, and working with those directly. Setting a breakpoint and walking through that method step by step, it is clear that the correct parts of that code get called in the correct way, but the DB simply does not get updated with the in-between values, only for the value that is explicitly getting moved.

Comment: [Log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880687/how-can-i-log-the-generated-sql-from-dbcontext-savechanges-in-my-program) the query and examine the actual SQL.

Comment: I actually solved my issue, although the bug that was causing my problem is quite embarrassing. Please see the solution I posted. Thank you very much for all your efforts, it was greatly appreciated.