# Entity Framework SaveChanges() bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I have a CRUD app deals with two objects, Cards and Logs. When a user creates, edits, or deletes a card, a new Log record is created in the Log table of the database. When the user creates a card, the Log record's NewCard value is JSON data and the OldCard value is null. When the user deletes a card, the Log record's OldCard value is JSON data and the NewCard is null.

However, whenever I delete a card, Entity Framework always creates this extra record circled in red:

[image]

Record 2101 is the result after `CreateNewLog(card, null)` in `IActionResult Create`. Record 2102 and 2103 are the result after `CreateNewLog(null, oldCard)` in `IActionResult Delete`. Record 2103 is the problem. How do I stop this record from being created?

**CardController.cs**

```
    private ICardData _cardData;
    private ILogData _logData;

    public CardController(ICardData cardData, ILogData logData)
    {
        _cardData = cardData;
        _logData = logData;
    }

    // POST api/card
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Card card)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _cardData.Add(card);
                CreateNewLog(card, null);

                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
                return Json(new { Data = card });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(new { Message = ex.Message });
        }

        return Json("Failed");
    }

    // DELETE api/card/1
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        Card oldCard = _cardData.Get(id).ShallowCopy();
        CreateNewLog(null, oldCard);

        _cardData.Delete(id);
    }

    public void CreateNewLog(Card newCard, Card oldCard)
    {
        Log newLog = new Log()
        {
            DateChanged = DateTime.Now,

            CardId = newCard == null ? oldCard.CardId : newCard.CardId,
            OldCard = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oldCard),
            NewCard = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newCard),
            User = "John Smith"
        };

        _logData.Add(newLog);
    }
```

**LogData.cs**

```
public class SqlLogData : ILogData
{
    private LitmusDbContext _context;

    public SqlLogData(LitmusDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Log> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Logs.ToList();
    }

    public Log Get(int id)
    {
        return _context.Logs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    }

    public void Add(Log newLog)
    {
        _context.Add(newLog);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

**CardData.cs**

```
public class SqlCardData : ICardData
    {
        private LitmusDbContext _context;

        public SqlCardData(LitmusDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Card> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Cards.ToList();
        }

        public Card Get(int id)
        {
            Card card = _context.Cards.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            return card;
        }

        public void Add(Card newCard)
        {
            _context.Add(newCard);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public int Commit()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return 0;
        }

        public void Update(Card newCard)
        {
            var oldCard = Get(newCard.Id);

            if (oldCard != null)
            {
                oldCard.CardId = newCard.CardId;
                oldCard.State = newCard.State;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var cardToDelete = Get(id);

            _context.Remove(cardToDelete);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be nice to see code of _cardData.Delete(id); if this one makes problems...

Comment: you can debug these methods from web and sql profiler to see which method is calling twice or where it is happening

Comment: Are you logging the SQL output?  It might give you some idea why this is happening.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880687/how-can-i-log-the-generated-sql-from-dbcontext-savechanges-in-my-program

Comment: Any SQL triggers doing it behind the scenes for you?

Comment: show the code of the class of this object _cardData. Is the _context static for any reason?

Comment: @JacobSobus Just added what you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how this is possible based on the code provided. At no point are new and old card both supplied to the CreateNewLog function but something is saving a serialised card to both the old/new columns.

Can you put a breakpoint in the CreateNewLog function and find out when both parameters are supplied, then view the call stack?

Comment: Whoops. You're right. Just realized every time I did a delete I was also calling the "Update" method from my front-end code.