# Includes Function Doesn't Select Some Entites

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i'm using this code

```
 public List<T>  GetWithNavigationTo(params string[] pathes)
        {
            (this._context as DbContext).Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            (this._context as DbContext).Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var data = Entities.AsQueryable();
            if (pathes != null)
            {
                foreach (string path in pathes)
                {
                    data = data.Include(path);
                }
            }
            return data.ToList();
        }
```

To Load Entities With Specified Navigation Path the problem is when i add navigation path i got some data loss i mean that some entities are not retrieved any solutions?

Comment: Please be more specific... give example include paths and example data, be specific about what you expect and what you get.

Comment: What SQL got [logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880687/how-can-i-log-the-generated-sql-from-dbcontext-savechanges-in-my-program)?

Comment: @SteveGreene  the problem solved thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem after revising SQL profiler. I saw that the query was generated using an `inner join` for the navigation properties, because the relation was required (non null values). So after allowing foreign key to be `null`, I got a `left join`, retrieving all values as I wanted.